# REST client with OAuth2 on stackapps

Tags: api, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm using Advanced REST Client in Chrome, to retrieve data from stackoverflow.
My goal is to replicate the result showed in this link:
[Usage of /me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Simply I have to show the json from **/me**.

First of all, which method I have to use in Advanced REST Client in Chrome to improve this through OAuth2?

1. Request token
2. Request access token
3. Signed request

If I use 1, I got the following: *error message: This method requires an access token*.

Then, I've tried with *implicit flow* to get access_token, but 2 requires me also request token secret and 3, access token secret.
So, I assume that the right way is 3, but I don't know how to find this **access token secret**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [StackExchange Authentication API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)